# Error in push notifications laravel

Tags: laravel, apple-push-notifications

I have using **davibennun/laravel-push-notification** package for push notifications in laravel.Everything is ok in local machine and it is successfully sending notification to IOS phone.
But in server it is showing error.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISEEc.png

Answer (score 0):

There is a good chance the php version on the server is not the same as the one on your development machine.

The notice refers to [OptionsResolver.php](https://github.com/symfony/options-resolver/blob/master/OptionsResolver.php#L980)

The specific feature was new in php 7.1 and refers to [Nullable types](http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php#migration71.new-features.nullable-types)

The version of php on your development machine is >= 7.1 and the version on the server is most probably <= 7.0